# Html Helper 'Action' is Undefined, Asp.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am brand new to ASP.NET Core MVC. I'll preface this question by saying I have read the other similar questions, but they weren't exactly the same problem I am having.

I am trying to implement a dynamic left side navigation, where each of the buttons are loaded from my database.

When I call `@Html.Action("NavMenu", "Nav")` in my "_Layout.cshtml" I get the error

> Error CS1929
> 'IHtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Action' and the best extension method overload 'UrlHelperExtensions.Action(IUrlHelper, string, object)' requires a receiver of type 'IUrlHelper'

One of the other similar questions led me to adding `@using System.Web.Mvc.Html` to the top of my "_ViewImports" and that leads to the error:

> CS7069: Reference to type 'RouteValueDictionary' Claims it is defined in 'System.Web', but it could not be found

Also the answer said `@html.Action()` should be built in to Core 2.0

using `@await Html.PartialAsync("_SideNav")` only works on my Index view, as that view has `@model IEnumerable<HSCWebApp.Models.HSCTable>` but my other views need `@model HSCWebApp.Models.HSCTable`, which causes "_SideNav" to crash

I am 100% open to other ways to implement this.

In NuGet I have installed:

- Entity Framework
- Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.App
- Microsoft.NETCore.App

EDIT:

I am also getting these warnings during build:

> Warning   NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.2' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

along with ones for Entity Framework, AspNet.Razor AspNet.Webpages

Would these warnings affect my references in some way?

---

Here are the files:

Controller: ("NavController.cs")

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using HSCWebApp.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace HSCWebApp.Controllers
{
    public class NavController : Controller
    {

        private readonly HSCWebAppContext _context;

        public NavController(HSCWebAppContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public ActionResult NavMenu()
            {
            
            NavViewModel nav = new NavViewModel();
            List<NavViewModel> navList = new List<NavViewModel>();

            var items = from n in _context.HSCTable select n;
            List<HSCTable> tableList = items.ToList<HSCTable>();


            for (int i = 0; i < tableList.Count(); i++)
            {
                nav.Id = tableList[i].ID;
                nav.DepartmentName = tableList[i].DepartmentName;
                nav.sel = tableList[i].sel;
                navList.Add(nav);
            }


            //var movies = from m in _context.Movie select m;
            //IEnumerable<NavViewModel> en = navList;
            //IEnumerable<HSCTable> en = tableList;

            return PartialView("_SideNav", tableList);
            }
        
    }
}
```

Model: ("NavViewModel.cs")

```
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    namespace HSCWebApp.Models
    {
        [Table("HSCTable")]
        public class NavViewModel
        {
            public NavViewModel(){
                int Id = this.Id;
                string DepartmentName = this.DepartmentName;
                string sel = this.sel;
                }
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
            public string sel { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

View: ("_SideNav.cshtml")

```
@model IEnumerable<HSCWebApp.Models.HSCTable>
@using System;
@using System.Collections;
@using System.Linq;

@{

    List<List<string>> navButtons = new List<List<string>>();
    int listIndex = 0;
    int INITIAL = 0;

    navButtons.Add(new List<string>());
    navButtons[listIndex].Add("");

}


<body>
    <div class="sidenav">
        @{

            foreach (var item in Model)
            {

                if (navButtons[listIndex][INITIAL].Equals(null) 
                    || navButtons[listIndex][INITIAL].Equals("")) 
                {
                    // if the list of lists is empty, add the department name
                    //initialize the list with with the department name
                    navButtons[listIndex][INITIAL] = item.DepartmentName;
                    //add the current select
                    navButtons[listIndex].Add(item.sel);
                }
                else if (navButtons[listIndex][INITIAL].Equals(item.DepartmentName)) 
                {
                    // if the current item's department name is the same 
                    // is the current list's department name, 
                    // add it's selectn
                    navButtons[listIndex].Add(item.sel);
                }
                else if (!item.DepartmentName.Equals(navButtons[listIndex][INITIAL]))
                {
                    // if the current item's department name 
                    // is not the same as the initial of this list, 
                    // create new list
                    navButtons.Add(new List<string>());
                    listIndex++;
                    navButtons[listIndex].Add(item.DepartmentName);
                    navButtons[listIndex].Add(item.sel);
                }
            }





            for (int i = 0; i < navButtons.Count; i++)
            {
                <button class="accordion"
                        onclick="openAccordion(this)">
                     @navButtons[i][INITIAL]
                </button>
                <div class="tab">
                    @for (int j = 1; j < navButtons[i].Count; j++)
                    {
                        <a class="tabLinks NoPrint" 
                           onclick="openTab(this)" 
                           asp-action="Details" 
                           asp-route-id="@navButtons[i][j]">
                              @navButtons[i][j].ToString() 
                        </a>
                    }
                </div>
            }

          //          @Url.Action("Details", "HSCTables", new { id = 1 })
          //onclick = "location.href='@Url.Action("Details","HSCTables", new { id = 1 })

        }

    </div>
</body>
```

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Do you have a view `NavMenu.cshtml` ?

Comment: @Llazar I do not, _SideNav is the view I want to be rendered, and replacing "NavMenu" with "_SideNav" still gives the same error. Unless I'm missing the point entirely?

Comment: Partials views are not made to work in that away. From your code I think you can create a viewComponent in that away. But if you decide to create the view `NavMenu` and from it you call the partial view `_SideNav`.

Comment: @Llazar I have been looking in to view components as well, but I followed a tutorial to make this partial view, so I'm guessing my `"_SideNav"` being a parameter in my controller's return is causing the issue/cannot be use this way? From what I've read, view components are the way to go for me, but I'd definitely would like to know why this is not working.

Comment: Your Entity Framework issues have nothing to do with this problem. You should remove any mention and the tag. Ask a new question if you're having trouble resolving that warning.

Comment: Html.Action was removed from ASP.NET Core and replaced by ViewComponent.

Comment: @mason That was just the first error, Ill change it to the MVC one, as i also got "AspNet.Mvc 5.2.2 was restored using .NetFramework, Version=v4.61... I thought it may have something that was affecting my dependencies.

Comment: @TiagoÁvila I guess this answers my question then. If you submit it as the answer, I'll mark it. Thank you all!

Comment: Why are you referencing ASP.NET MVC 5? That's for .NET Framework and the old MVC that ran on it. It's not for .NET Core or ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @mason okay, I see. I removed that. That was a part of my attempts at resolving my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Posting as an answer".

Like I said, Html.Action was removed from ASP.NET Core and was replaced for ViewComponents.

There is a good tutorial in Microsoft Docs, you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1). Explaining about the advantages, the place when you can put the View for your ViewComponent, how to use parameters and so on.

Comment: Yes, I read that document, but I had already done all the 'work' for partial view. Being an amateur, I just thought "why redo all this work for View Components, when I can just use Partial Views" 

I wish they mentioned that Partial Views were removed.

Comment: @ZaeemQ actualy, partial view still is in ASP.NET Core, you can call a partial view using '@await Html.PartialAsync("_PartialName")'. Just Html.Action was replaced.

Comment: Oh woops that's what I meant. I used `partialAsync` but it was only working for my index page, not my other pages. Partial Async was inheriting the parent's viewbag, which worked for my index view, but not for the others , due to the way `_SideNav` was written.

Answer (score 3):

As @Tiago Ávila said, `Html.Action` was removed from Asp.NET Core, so I stopped trying to do this with `@html.action` but rather with View Components, as @Llazar suggested, and it worked!

My View Component:

```
public class NavViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {

        private readonly HSCWebAppContext _context;

        public NavViewComponent(HSCWebAppContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
        {

            NavViewModel nav = new NavViewModel();
            List<NavViewModel> navList = new List<NavViewModel>();

            var items = from n in _context.HSCTable select n;
            List<HSCTable> tableList = items.ToList<HSCTable>();


            for (int i = 0; i < tableList.Count(); i++)
            {
                nav.Id = tableList[i].ID;
                nav.DepartmentName = tableList[i].DepartmentName;
                nav.sel = tableList[i].sel;
                navList.Add(nav);
            }

            return View("_SideNav",tableList);
        }

    }
```

My call in _Layout:

`@await Component.InvokeAsync("Nav")`

Nothing else needed to be changed. Thanks for your help!