# The @Html.Action() is not available

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I want use partial view in asp.net core mvc:

I want call a action method of partial view in a view this is `@Html.Action("ActionMethod","ControllerName")` or `@Html.RenderAction("ActionMethod","ControllerName")` . But they is not available and i see compiler error in **vscode**. how I call it?

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   ...
</head>
<body>
     @Html.Action("TestPartial") 
</body>
</html>
```

And the compiler error is:

> /.../PerojectName/Views/Home/Index.cshtml(10,7): error CS1929:
> 'IHtmlHelper'  does not contain a definition for 'Action' and
> the best extension method overload
> 'UrlHelperExtensions.Action(IUrlHelper, string)' requires a receiver
> of type 'IUrlHelper'  [/.../PerojectName/PartialView_Example.csproj]

Also in controller I see compiler error in `[ChildActionOnly]` .

My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace PartialView_Example.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult TestPartial()
        {
            ViewBag.Text="It is test";
            return PartialView();            
        } 
    }
}
```

And compiler error is:

> /.../ProjectName/Controllers/HomeController.cs(18,10): error CS0246:
> The type or  namespace name 'ChildActionOnlyAttribute' could not be
> found (are you missing a using  directive or an assembly reference?)
> /.../ProjectName/Controllers/HomeController.cs(18,10): error CS0246:
> The type or  namespace name 'ChildActionOnly' could not be found (are
> you missing a using directive or  an assembly reference?)

I using vscode and .Net Sdk 5.0.301 in linux ubuntu.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Html Helper 'Action' is Undefined, Asp.NET Core 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52972732/html-helper-action-is-undefined-asp-net-core-2-2)

Comment: You can check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52972732/html-helper-action-is-undefined-asp-net-core-2-2?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Harkiratsingh this is the same link I posted earlier. In cases like this, we shouldn't post answers. The question is marked as "duplicate" and closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ChildActionOnlyAttribute`, `@Html.Action` and `@Html.RenderAction` are not available in .NET Core MVC. These are available as part of ASP.NET MVC framework. `ChildActionOnlyAttribute` can be used from the namespace `System.Web.Mvc`.

Alternatively, in .NET Core MVC, you can use the View Components. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1) is the link to the MS Document.